# Ubuntu 12.04 detect notebook driver as vmware

Tags: 12.04, drivers, intel-graphics, cedarview

I bought samsung N100 notebook yesterday. I installed ubuntu 12.04(only os). After successfully installed i found that unity 3D is not working. So run jocky-3D for additional driver. I found two driver in list and installed.

```
drm driver for the intel GMA500
intel Cedarview graphics driver
```

After reboot, visual looks good but still unity 3D didn't load. system settings returns

```
Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)
```

Then I ran unity test.

```
PVRDRIInitPVR2D: PVR2D device index (0) **OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.**
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 8.0.4

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

Surprising news is that **OpenGL vendor** string returns **VMware, Inc**. What does this means? Ubuntu detects my notebook as VMware client??

Additional info:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20

VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm running kubuntu 12.04 on a cedarview atom 2600 netbook.  There's an option in kde settings to select opengl or xrender.  If you select opengl it will change itself to xrender.

Myself I'm convinced that the cedarview driver packages don't support opengl.  Period.  I don't think you're ever going to get full graphics performance out if that gpu in linux.  It's closed source.  I use it on a netbook so I don't care personally, though I can see how others might.

I tried the alpha 2 and beta versions of kubuntu 13.04.  That has the drivers incorporated into the kernel (linux kernel >= 3.7).  No driver downloads needed, but the same situation.  No opengl capability.

Which will also mean you won't be able to use 12.10 or later unity releases.  They dropped the 2D option.

This may not  be what you'll want to hear but I'd just install xubuntu or kubuntu.  KDE (kubuntu) uses similar memory to unity and it's faster and much more powerful.  I find Unity/compiz/gnome3 slow and buggy anyway.  I'd never use it on my i3 laptop, which is way more powerful than my netbook.